# Drupal 9 contextual filter on url alias

Tags: url, view, alias, drupal-9, pathauto

With Drupal 9 installation I am using apthauto to create alias pattern for content type using multiple fields data.
I need to create a REST export view for single node with contextual filter matching url alias generated for the nodes.
You dont get url alias as a field to populate in the result. and url alias not available in contextual filter selection.

I have tried contextual filer on ID and thought selecting 'Use path alias' will work to filter [see current setting here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6yBy.png)